# why asp.net MVC controllers are not considered as RESTful web service

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rest

I have an asp.net web application, now let say a user send a POST action method to the application using following URL `Myapplication.com/Customer/Edit/120`, then this URL will update the customer who have ID=120 with the data sent.

So this is the same as calling a web service, since you are integrating with the application (in this case Update a customer) using URLs, so why this is not consider as having a RESTfull web service!

Answer (score 2):

What exactly is a web service ? And how do you differentiate between a web page and web service.

These are just different terms of retrieving some Resource. Either with Web Service or Web Page, you are just requesting for a resource. The representation is fixed for web page i.e its always HTML. If from my web service instead of returning Json or XML , if it start serving HTML would then make it a web page ?

I think the whole concept of web service came with SOAP world. With Rest there is nothing as web service or web page. There are mere different representation for a resource(json, xml, html, image).

Further to answer your

> so why this is not consider as having a RESTfull web service!

Microsoft has launched [Asp.Net Web API](http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2012/03/05/introduction-to-the-asp-net-web-api.aspx), which is nothing but pure MVC to serve content.